# moment.js uses the month as day instead the day

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs

I'm using currently moment.js (moment-with-locales.js - v.2.14.1) in my project. I want to remove the time of my datetime string to get only the date. But if I use the `.format()` method of moment.js I got an incorrect date.

I want to format this datetime string:

from ' **08.10.2016 11:00** ' to ' **08.10.2016** '

Here is a snipped that I used in my angular project:

```
var date = moment('08.10.2016 11:00').format('DD.MM.YYYY')
console.log(date)
```

If I run this I got this output

```
10.08.2016
```

instead of
    08.10.2016

The funny thing is, if I want to get the timestamp (milliseconds) of my datetime string, it works perfect. Example:

```
  var dateStart = moment('08.10.2016 19:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').valueOf()
  console.log(dateStart)
```

Will return

```
1475946000000 -> Sat Oct 08 2016 19:00:00 GMT+0200
```

How can I get the correct Date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your locale. `en-US` locate means moment will parse by "month day year". So, you need to parse with the pattern as well:

```
var date = moment('08.10.2016 11:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').format('DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Comment: ...and the documentation is at [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfect!